# Dynamic SQL Pivot in PHP

Tags: php, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

I have been on this problem for a couple of days without any Success. Any help would be grateful.

I'm using a dynamic Pivot which works when run in SQL, however when I try to run this query in PHP I get the following error.

> Warning:mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect
>   syntax near ','. (severity 15) in XXXXX

I've narrowed it down to how I build the variable in SQL. Although this works in SQL, PHP as a problem with it. I've tested it by defining the variable as `SELECT @ColName = '[GEN1.1], [GEN2.2]'` which works. I've also tried using a for loop to build the array which didn't work.

```
SELECT @ColName = ISNULL(@ColName + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(GEN)
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

An example of my data and SQL query is below.

```
DECLARE @ColName AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @ColName = ISNULL(@ColName + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(GEN)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GEN FROM TB) AS Gens

SET @DPQ =  N'SELECT STAGE, ' + @ColName + ' 
                 INTO #TB2
                 FROM  (see below)
                 PIVOT (SUM(QTY)
                   FOR GEN IN (' + @ColName + ')) 
                    AS PVTTable
                 ORDER BY STAGE'

EXEC sp_executesql @DPQ
```

Table

```
Stage   GEN QTY
A   GEN1.1  50
A   GEN2.2  125
A   GEN2.2  75
C   GEN1.1  100
C   GEN2.2  25
D   GEN1.1  199
D   GEN2.2  50
```

Comment: Created a stored procedure and `CALL` it.

Comment: Yea I tried that but got the same error which surprised me.

Comment: I've gone down the route of spliting my query in Php by doing the following 1) running a query that gets my parameters. 2) Define these as a PHP string. 3) Run a 2nd query with the PHP string included.  This works but the script seems slower and makes future modifications more complex. Would be neater to run it as 1 query.

Comment: show us PHP code also